# How do you remove standard headers from the HTTP response of Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, http, security, azure-functions

Is it possible to remove these headers?

I have a .NET solution with several Azure functions that show all the header information in the HTTP response when they are called. There is no web.base.config type file that I can add 'removeServerHeader = true' which I have used to solve this problem previously in ASP.NET projects.

However, in my azure function solution there is only a host.json file and I don't think this can be used to do something similar.

I have seen a fix for this in the git repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1237) but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it so the headers are removed.

Can anyone help with this please? Or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: What headers you want to remove?cause in this fix `X-Powered-By` is already removed, and provide your environment information for test.

Comment: I would like to remove the server header ideally. I’m also unsure of how to implement this fix, is it as simple as installing the extension to my solution? Thanks.

Comment: The other problem is that I think this fix does not work for azure functions on a consumption plan like mine is.

Comment: Which Function version are you running on? I just checked a v3 Function and I don't even see a Server header in the response

Comment: Thanks for checking. I am running on v1 - perhaps the solution is to upgrade to Azure Function v3, which will also mean upgrading my project to .NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the fix you link is about `ASP.NET version header`, this is fixed in the function v1, the release version is [v1.0.11510](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v1.0.11510), so you won't get this header.

Then is about server header, yes in my test I will get this header too with v1 function Here is the [fix detail](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/commit/88615cdb573c34ce076ce65dacf7746e5e1735e7) , it removes `X-Powered-By` and server header and ther version should be [2.0.12493](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/2.0.12493). So actually you don't have to use the v3 function, the latest v2 function already remove these headers.